# Written UTF-16 character to a file by using UTF-8 charset output stream in java but resulting data on file is still UTF-16. why?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Created a simple java program to see if utf 8 charset can save utf16 character, and it does able to save it.  Why?
If UTF-08 can save UTF-16 characters than whats the difference in using UTF-16 and UTF-8.

both test character's unicode value is beyond UTF-8 range i.e. 256.

✈ unicode value: 9992
❄ unicode value: 10052

please see the sample program:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class UTFSizeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
        write("UTF-16");
        write("UTF-8");
        write(null);
    }

    private static void write(String utf) throws IOException {
        final String fileName = "someFile" + utf;

        Writer writer;

        if (utf == null) {
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        } else {
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), utf);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            writer.write("✈ ❄");
            writer.write("\n");
        }

        writer.close();

        System.out.println(fileName + " size: "+ new File(fileName).length());
    }
}
```

Data written same on both files using utf-16 and utf-8 :-
✈ ❄
✈ ❄

Size of the files is also almost the same for UTF-16 and UTF-8 as can seen on console output.
Console output is following:-
Default Charset=UTF-8
someFileUTF-16 size: 18
someFileUTF-8 size: 16
someFilenull size: 16

If utf-08 can save 16 bits unicode just fine fine than why to use uff-16 in java.

thank you.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't match the actual question. But the final question: why use UTF-16 files, well, guess what, it isn't done very often indeed.

Comment: And i also noticed that my special characters are not even recognized well on chrome browser on windows but they were on Safari on Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Created a simple java program to see if utf 8 charset can save utf16 character

It can.  UTF-8 and UTF-16 are just different encodings for the same Unicode character set.  Both encodings are designed to support all Unicode codepoints, both present and the foreseeable future.

> and it does able to save it. Why?

Because they both support the same Unicode codepoints.  Converting between the various UTFs is a loss-less operation, by design.

> If UTF-08 can save UTF-16 characters than whats the difference in using UTF-16 and UTF-8.

UTF-8 is primarily preferred over UTF-16 because:

1. UTF-8 is backwards compatible with 7bit ASCII, so a lot of legacy code can be migrated to UTF-8 without breaking.
2. For most languages, particularly latin-based ones, UTF-8 is more compact than UTF-16, thus saving memory, disk space, and bandwidth.  However, there are cases, primarily Asian languages, but also symbols (as in your example) where UTF-16 is actually more compact than UTF-8.

> please see the sample program:-
>   ...
>   Data written same on both files using utf-16 and utf-8 :-

Yes, they *represent* the same Unicode codepoints, so they are *rendered* the same by a Unicode-aware text viewer/editor.  But their physical bytes are very different:

```
✈
UTF-8:    e2 9c 88
UTF-16LE: 08 27
UTF-16BE: 27 08

❄
UTF-8:    e2 9d 84
UTF-16LE: 44 27
UTF-16BE: 27 44
```

> Size of the files is also almost the same for UTF-16 and UTF-8 as can seen on console output.

In the above example, you have chosen 2 Unicode codepoints that do not require UTF-16 surrogate pairs to encode them, so they use 2 bytes instead of 4 bytes in UTF-16.  In UTF-8, the take 3 bytes each, but the size difference is reduced by the 1-byte `U+0020 SPACE` character in between them.  Try writing longer strings with a bigger mix of low and high codepoint values, and you should see a much wider variation in file sizes.

> If utf-08 can save 16 bits unicode just fine fine than why to use uff-16 in java.

Although UTF-8 and UTF-16 are both variable-length encodings, UTF-16 tends to have less-variable lengths than UTF-8. All of the codepoints within UTF-8's 1-, 2-, and 3-byte formats fit within UTF-16's 2-byte format, making UTF-16 closer to fixed-length than UTF-8.  That is also means UTF-16 is easier to seek forwards and (particularly) backwards within, you only have to jump 2 or 4 bytes per codepoint, whereas with UTF-8 you have to jump 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes per codepoint, so decoding logic is a bit more complex in UTF-8 than UTF-16.

Keep in mind that when Java, Windows, etc adopted Unicode, it was before UTF-16 existed, when all available codepoints at the time easily fit within UCS-2, which is a fixed-length encoding.  It wasn't until later on that Unicode outgrew UCS-2 and UTF-16 was invented to replace it.  By then, it was too late to re-write code that had been migrated to Unicode, so UTF-16 had to maintain backwards compatibility with UCS-2.  Besides, much Unicode data used in the real world still tends to fit within UCS-2, only higher codepoints really require the extra bytes used to encode UTF-16 surrogates.

So, that usually makes UTF-16 a more suitable choice for processing data. It is a better compromise between memory usage and processing overhead than UTF-8, at least when dealing with non-ASCII characters.  But UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII, and it tends to be a more suitable format for storing and exchanging data.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question because of my ignorance.
I though UTF-8 can only save character point upto 8 bits and UTF-16 is required for Unicode or Unicode characters means character represented by 2 bytes or 16 bits.

But after reading through some forums i realized that UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are all different encoding styles for the Unicode characters and in fact UTF-8 can represent the character upto 6 bytes/48 bits.

thanks

Comment: No, UTF-8 never takes more than 4 bytes, just like UTF-16 and UTF-32.  Only UTF-32 is always 4 bytes.  The other two vary.

Comment: *Technically* UTF-8 can go up to 6 bytes (to handle Unicode codepoints up to 31 bits), but is artificially limited by [RFC 3629](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629) to 4 bytes for compatibility with UTF-16 (which can handle codepoints up to 21 bits).